# How do I share a set of DLLs, dependencies, and sample programs?

Tags: c++, dll, deployment

I'm working on an C++ API/SDK, and I'm ready to distribute the alpha version for testing.  It won't be available to the general public, I just want to send it around and have people install it on their machines to make sure everything works as it should.  Here is a list of what I want to bundle in the distribution:

- The library I've made.  This includes .lib and .dll files, as well as some headers.
- Dependencies: headers and libs for all of the project dependencies, including OpenCV.
- Source code for sample programs.  I have a Visual Studio solution with some sample code that I'd like to share.
- Utility applications: a few support applications (.exe files) that I'd like to include without sharing the source code.

Ideally I'd like to get all of the libraries into the PATH so that the user can use them in new projects without having to specify a precise include path.  Would bundling everything together with a batch file be appropriate?  Or is there a better/more professional/more reliable way?

I am currently using VS Express, but I could upgrade to Pro if it's totally necessary.

Comment: _"Would bundling everything together with a batch file be appropriate?"_ Use some tool to create an installer. That's probably less error prone.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?  I'm new at this and don't really know where to start looking, or even what search vocabulary to use.

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+installer+for+windows

Comment: Yes, I've done that search.  The top hits are all about how to make an MSI installer.  I'm working in 64-bit, and I'm not able to creat 64-bit installers using VS Express.  And as I mentioned, upgrading to Pro is an option, but $500 is not a throwaway amount of money for me, so I'm hoping there is a different approach I can take.  Have you ever used AdvancedInstaller?

Comment: Or Wix Toolset?

Comment: There are many, commercial and open source.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using WiX.  It's very tricky to get the hang of initially, but I found [this tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/) to be helpful.